# If $g''(x) = x(x+2)(x-3)^2$, then the graph of $g$ has inflection points when is equal to what $x$?

Tags: derivatives

If $g''(x) = x(x+2)(x-3)^2$, then the graph of $g$ has inflection points when is equal to what $x$? (No calculator allowed)

Now I have been taught that $f''(x) = 0$ gives you the point of inflection, which may be a stationary point or highest rate of change. So naturally I said $x$ = $-2, 0$ and $3$. However when I checked the answer this is incorrect. My textbook answer gives $-2$ and $0$.

So why can't $x = 3$ be an inflection point? How can I derive this information from the equation? Is it because of the power of $2$ in $(x-3)^2$ as it can be a repeated root?

Answer (score 1):

The condition that $g^{\prime\prime}(x) = 0$ isn't the only condition that needs to be satisfied for $x$ to be an inflection point. You must also have that the concavity flips at $x$, which happens when the sign of $g^{\prime\prime}$ flips at $x$.

So, $x=3$ isn't an inflection point because when $x<3$ then the sign of $g^{\prime\prime}$ doesn't change because $(x-3)^2>0$ and clearly when $x>3$ then $(x-3)^2>0$.

Answer (score 0):

An [Inflection Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) is defined as the point where a change in curvature occurs, that is, $f''(x)$ changes sign. If you look at the graph for $g''(x)$:

[image]

You can clearly see that $g''(x)$ does not change sign at $x = -3$, which is why this is not an inflection point of $g(x)$